# Can't reproduce app freeze, how to debug it?

Tags: ios

So we recently sent out an update of our app (swift) into the App Store. Then after a day some of our users who upgraded reported that the app is *"freezing"* and it not functional.

What's weird is we tried to install the same build of the app from the App Store in our devices and everything seems working as expected. We tried to use some of the users' account who encounter the *"freezing"* but all tests seems working fine. The number of reports that the app is freezing is keep increasing and we don't know how to fix or debug it for us to actually know what's happening.

The affected users already tried to reinstall the app but still the issue persists.

Does anyone know how to debug this kind of issue? Is there a tool that can use to debug this?

Comment: If your app uses the internet, you may want to see what happens if you have a slow internet connection. Perhaps you’re doing some network request on the main thread, and some users have a slower internet connection than you.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is usually caused by doing something time consuming on the main thread.

In my case it was saving something into User Defaults using Codable. It turned out that this did not scale. For small amounts of data I never encountered an issue, but users with a lot of data found that the interface froze for half a minute. I solved it by moving that operation off into a background thread and also changing my data storage model.

So look for something your app does that might not scale up when there’s a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

We found the cause of the issue, it a "dead lock" caused by a ReverseGeocode that wrapped in a BlockingObservable (RxSwift) that was incorrectly call within the main thread. This will occur when the ReverseGeocode request takes time than the expected, weren't able to reproduce it because in our office we get the reverseGeocoding response in a matter of second or two.

To fix the issue, we just wrapped the code that calls the ReverseGeocode into a separate thread so it won't block the main thread.